# Get a list of element from MYSQL join query

Tags: mysql

The result I'd like to have is :

> "id":1,
>   "skills":[ {"skill_name":"Product
>   Design"},{"skill_name":"Graphic
>   Design"} ]

The result I have is :

> {"id":1,"skills":"Product Design"},{"id":1,"skills":"Graphic Design"}

My query is  :

```
select `u`.`id`, `s`.`skill_name` as `skills`
from `users` as `u`
    left join `user_skills` as `s` on `u`.`id` = `s`.`user_id` 
where `u`.`id` = 1
```

I've tried GROUP BY user.id or SELECT DISTINCT but no luck.

How can I obtain an array of the multiple result for each id?

Comment: You have to reformat it with application code to format it as a JSON array of objects. But you can use `GROUP_CONCAT(skill_name)` to return a delimited string of `skills` per `id` along with `GROUP BY id` if it suits the code you're using this in.  SQL itself only ever returns flat 2D result sets.

Comment: If you need assistance post-processing the SQL result into the desired JSON, please post the code that handles this query.

Comment: This is a simplified version of the query.
The query used get lots of info from 7 tables using join.
(I use knex as a query builder)
What I'm trying to find a workaround for is to have the "basic" query, and then loop over the result to "inject" the list of skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, group_concat(s.skill_name) AS skills
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN user_skills AS s ON u.id = s.user_id
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY u.id
```

The out put will be:

```
id skills
-- ------------------------------
1  Product Design, Graphic Design
```

If you really want the output in the following format:

> {"id":1, "skills":[ {"skill_name":"Product Design"},{"skill_name":"Graphic Design"} ]}

Then try this SQL -- (crazy version):

```
SELECT 
  '{"id":', u.id, ', skills:[', 
  group_concat(concat('{"skill_name":"', s.skill_name, '"}')) AS skills,
  ']}'
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN user_skills AS s ON u.id = s.user_id
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY u.id
```

SELECT concat('{"id":',id,', skills:['), group_concat(concat('{"skill_name":"',skill_name,'"}')) AS skills, ']'